# UIView Flip Animation Too Fast - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview

I tried animating a sequence of UIViews from a mutable array to simulate this [animation](https://vimeo.com/11318617)

```
for(int k = 0; k< [imageViewCarrier count] ; k++){
    UIView *transformingView = [imageViewCarrier objectAtIndex:k];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:30.0 animations:^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:30.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView transitionFromView:transformingView toView:splicedImageView duration:3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:NULL];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        NSLog(@"Transition done");
    }];

}
```

The animation seems to be too fast. Any suggestions on this. Did search some documentation but couldn't figure it out. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I think you might be doing it the wrong way. If memory serves me, when using `[UIView animinateWithDuration:animiations:completion:]`, you shouldn't call `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];` and `[UIView commitAnimations];` or `setAnimationDelegate:` or `setAnimationDuration:` for that matter, since they are the old way of animating views that you had to use before the block-based methods were introduced.

I'd try leaving those out and see what happens. Also, note that the duration parameter is in seconds, so `30.0` seems a bit too long.

And just a style note: the "proper" Objective-C way to iterate through a collection is as follows:

```
for(UIView* view in imageViewCarrier){
   [view doSomething];
}
```